# Excel formula find duplicates with multiple criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to create an excel formula that locates duplicate entries for an employee. Records are pulled from two different systems and then the data is dumped into excel. Below is an example of how the records look. If an employee performed the same task on the same day that is a duplicate.

I've tried the index/match, index/match match, but it will only return the first duplicate (if it even works to do that). I have very little experience with arrays and I've been trying to figure those out to no avail - I feel like this should be easier than I'm making it??

Ideally would want it to return "yes/no" or "duplicate" when a duplicate value is found.

**Set One**

```
Client       Employee           Date
Bob Jones     Sally Smith       1/1/2018
Jane Smith    Tom Jones         2/1/2018
```

**Set Two**

```
Client      Date        Employee        Task
Bob Jones   1/1/2018    Sally Smith      1
Bob Jones   1/1/2018    Sally Smith      2
Jane Smith  2/1/2018    Tom Jones        1
Jane Smith  2/1/2018    Tom Jones        1
```

Comment: What is the end goal? Are you just trying to remove duplicates?  (There's built-in functionality for that.)

Comment: The end goal is to identify the duplicates for the user of the report, so they can take that information, and review it in another system. As it is now, they have to review everything on Report 1 in the system to see if it might be a duplicate (which takes them 2 full work days). The user can't work solely with Report 2 as, when pulled, it returns all records ever in the system. Report 1 returns the records from the current payroll. 

And no, we can't do anything to Report 2 so it only returns what we need. That would be logical, so that can't happen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to show an example using formula based conditional formatting. First you need to select more rules in conditional formatting as shown in the picture below.

[image: mr.excel]

After that you pick the option to use the formula to determine which cells to format, and use a formula that looks like this, it's a basic COUNTIFS formula that checks whether the records match at least one other record in the table in all columns that you write down.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$10;$A1;$B$1:$B$10;$B1;$C$1:$C$10;$C1)>1
```

Note that the default format that the Excel offers you is actually a basic format, so you need to make sure to change it so you know whether the formula is working or not.

Comment: I think I failed to completely explain my problem (figures). So set 1 needs to be compared to set 2, as well as finding the duplicates in set 2. Set 2 contains more data than set 1. I only need the information for records in set 1. [For example](https://imgur.com/a/XtDeMj7).

Answer (score 0):

I might still be misunderstanding what you're trying to do, but if you want the first table to have a count of how many rows in second table have matching `Client&Employee&Date` to the first table, you could use `COUNTIF` (or perhaps `VLOOKUP`), with the aid of a *["helper column"](https://exceljet.net/glossary/helper-column)* in the second table.

The helper column would concatenate `Client&Employee&Date` from the second row.

<sub>Forgive the weird image example... my beta version of Excel 2019 keeps crashing today and I'm not 100% sure this is what you're trying to do.  (If it *is* what you need to do but don't understand the image, comment @ me and I will explain further.)</sub>

[image: img]